# show that $(a+b)^{p^n}\equiv a^{p^n} + b^{p^n}\pmod p$ where $p$ is a prime and n$\ge$1.

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I need to show that $(a+b)^{p^n}\equiv a^{p^n} + b^{p^n}\pmod p$ where $p$ is a prime and n$\ge$1.

I came up with the following:

$a^{p^n} + b^{p^n}\equiv a+b\pmod p$

But I don't know if I can use this, or how I should continue. How do I do this?

Comment: Just use Fermat's Little Theorem repeatedly.  $a \equiv a^p \equiv (a^p)^p \equiv \dots \pmod p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fermat's little theorem repeatedly $$(a+b)^{p^n}\equiv(a+b)(\text{mod}~ p) $$ and you've already got $$a^{p^n}+b^{p^n}\equiv a+b(\text{mod}~p)$$. combine both.